# Displaying an HTML file with a JS inside an iPython notebook

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, jupyter-notebook

I have a piece of code in an iPython notebook that programmatically generates a folder named 'sound' containing the following files: index.html, canvas.js, graph.js and style.css.

If I open index.html in my browser, I can see exactly the output I want: a graph with a nice JS animation representing vectors in and out of a process I am modeling.

[image: network visualization]

However, I would like to display the HTML file from inside the iPython notebook itself.

For that, I type the following code:

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame('/Users/useird/Desktop/sound/index.html', width=700, height=350)
```

Which returns the following:
[image: 404 error ipython notebook]

I am not an expert with css or js, but I think that iPython can display js inside an iframe, so what's wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To explicitly answer this question, I post my comment here again.

IPython uses the [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org) web server engine to serve the html pages. Per default, the web server cannot access files above the start directory. Otherwise, this would be a severe security exposure.
Hence, to make your data available for the web server you have to place it in the notebook starting directory or in a subdirectory.

This applies not only to html pages, but also to images you want to display using  tags.